# my website doesn't retrieve data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that communicate with sql server with entity framework.

Now i want to upload my website in a server. I've created database 
in that server and restore my local database backup in it then i published my application in filesystem and upload it in server.

My problem is connection string in `web.config`i know that in connection string we should define data source , initial catalog , user id and password and my connection string is like this :

```
<add name="Bestshooter1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DomainModel.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.DomainModel.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.DomainModel.Model.msl;connection string=&quot;Data Source=./MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=bestshoo_Database;User Id=bestshoo_DatabaseAdmin;Password=******;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
```

But it still does not work, what is wrong?

Comment: *But it still does not work* Define this, any error or log that you get?

Comment: Check the string with your hosting company as well.

Comment: Do you use edmx ??

Comment: Log into the database using those credentials as well.  Just to test, might prove that it is the security configuration on the remote database.

Comment: Data source should be an `IP`.

Answer (score 0):

The password of your connection string is ***** please replace it with original password.
Some servers allow you to deploy your database on server and provide connection string to use in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with **Provider Name**:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=YourDbName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add ProviderName to tag `<add />`.

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=YourDbName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```